# SSIS: How to I specify the server for the file connection manager (specifying existing directory)?

Tags: ssis

I'm fairly new to SSIS and am having trouble figuring out something that seems like it should be straight forward:

On server A, I have 10 files in "C:\SourceFiles\Patients" (these files are PDFs). I know the names of these 10 files and they won't change.  Also, there is a server B which is the DB server and is where the SSIS package will be located. My goal is to loop through a DB table containing patients, add some patient data to the 10 source files (renaming the file) and then save this new file to server A.

I have most of this running already. Currently, all of this is happening in a script task using ADO.NET for the DB access (I'm already accessing the DB table on server B) and I'm accessing the source files on my local C drive.

I am having trouble figuring out how to specify server A in the Package Configuration for the source files. I have a file connection which specifies an existing folder (C:\SourceFiles\Patients), but it only specifies the location of the folder NOT the server. How to I specify server A for this file connection? Or, how do I use this file connection with a server A connection? I'm having real difficulty grasping this for some reason!!

The technologies I'm using are:
Visual Studio 2008, 
C# in the SSIS script task,
ADO.NET in the SSIS script task and
SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (SSIS package will be imported here).

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some issues with what you are trying to do.

PDF is an image format (an image of a document) and as such is not easily manipulated by SSIS.  Generally if you are acting on a file from within SSIS, it would be a flat file of some sort, like a CSV or some other text format.

Using a script task to do all of your work within SSIS is failing to use the power of SSIS properly.  If all you have in your SSIS project is a script task, you should just be using C# or VB.net directly and not involving SSIS in your project at all.

That all being said, you should access your files on server A using UNC (Universal Naming Convention) paths.  You will need to pay close attention to your permissions within SSIS to make this work.  When an SSIS job runs, it runs under a specific user, usually the SQL Server Agent user, and that user will need permissions to access the folder on server A remotely.  When all of these permissions are  set correctly, you can use something akin to \\ServerA\ShareName\Patients\ as the pointer to your directory with pdf's in it.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the information on UNCs. I'll certainly look into them. The line was a bit blurry for me on whether the script task would take care of this or if I should be focusing more on the SSIS package.